# Sogo-tool runnng as cron and crashing server but apt says it's not installed

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I've got a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS dev server setup and today it crashed. I found the following log entry in syslog right before the crash.

> Mar  6 05:36:01 SERVERNAME CRON[7172]: (sogo) CMD (/usr/sbin/sogo-tool expire-sessions 30 >/dev/null 2>&1; /usr/sbin/sogo-ealarms-notify >/dev/null 2>&1)

But when I try to type:

> sudo apt-get remove sogo-tool

I get:

> E: Unable to locate package sogo-tool

When I try:

> sudo apt-get remove sogo

I get:

> Package 'sogo' not installed, so not removed

But when I try running:

> sogo-tool

I get:

> The program 'sogo-tool' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install sogo

So I started checking my crontabs, and there's nothing sogo-related in there either! I checked monthly, weekly, daily, and hourly. No sogo...

So it appears a piece of software that isn't installed has a cron that crashes the server, and the commands for uninstalling it all don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Found it! There was a file in /etc/cron.d called "sogo."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! There was a file in /etc/cron.d called "sogo."